# reverse half of the list

Tags: c, linked-list, reverse

I was asked to write a function reverseHalves() that rearranges a given linked list so that the first half of the nodes is moved to the back of the second half. e.g.

Given a linked list `[1 2 3 4 5 6]`, the resulting list should be `[4 5 6 1 2 3]`.
When given a linked list with an *odd number of nodes*,  the list should be split with the first half  having an additional node. That is, given the list `[1 2 3 4 5]`, the resulting list should be `[4 5 1 2 3]`.

But the my function will give a infinite output...

```
typedef struct _listnode{
    int item;
    struct _listnode *next;
} ListNode;

typedef struct _linkedlist{
    int size;
    ListNode *head;
    ListNode *tail;
} LinkedList;
```

Here are the functions I used:

```
// printList will print out the value in every nodes until there is a NULL
void printList(LinkedList *ll);
ListNode * findNode(LinkedList *ll, int index);
int insertNode(LinkedList *ll, int index, int value);

void reverseHalves(LinkedList *ll)
{
    int index;
    ListNode *new_head, *new_tail;
    new_head = NULL;
    new_tail = NULL;

    // determine the index of new tail, and the new head which is index+1*
    index = (ll->size + 1) / 2;

    // get the new head by findNode func,whose index is index+1 
    // make new_head point to the node found*
    new_head = findNode(ll, index);

    // make initial tail->next be the initial head*
    ll->tail->next = ll->head;

    // set the head to be the new head
    ll->head = new_head;

    insertNode(ll, ll->size, -1);
    new_tail = findNode(ll, ll->size);
    new_tail = NULL;
}
```

Comment: What's an infinite output?

Comment: Also, with the whitespace usage you've presented, I'm not surprised even you don't understand your own code...

Comment: when I tried to print the list, it will keep printing. But I have set the tail to be NULL...

Comment: @userXXX Step 1: read up on "scope" of the variables in C. Step 2: be surprised/enlightened. Step 3: fix it (in a way only **you** can deduce since you haven't posted the definition of the `ListNode` structure).

Comment: OMG! I changed some code. But I forget to change the comments..I will edit them again..

Comment: your are making loop here `ll->tail->next = ll->head;`

Comment: This operation is called rotating a list by 'x' positions - only thing is here you are rotating it by half the size of the list.

Comment: @Baller What on Earth are you doing with the formatting? Rolled back because your edit made the practically unreadable (again).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an approximate gist:

```
new_head_index = (ll->size+1) / 2;
new_tail_index = new_head_index - 1;

if (new_tail_index < 0)
    return;

new_head = findNode(ll,new_head_index);
new_tail = findNode(ll,new_tail_index);

ll->tail->next = ll->head;
new_tail->next = NULL
ll->head = new_head;
```

Comment: Could you spend some time to explain why my code failed as well?

Comment: What you had was mostly right. The last 3 lines of code you wrote is where your code fails. First, I can guess what insertNode does, but it's unnecessary since you only need to rewire next pointers. Second, you set the value of new_tail twice, but you probably wanted the last line to be new_tail->next = NULL. Presumably findNode can cope with a circular list.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to code the problem in steps.

1)Firstly create a list.

2)split the list ,to get two lists.

3)add the tail of the second  list to the head of the first list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code for reversing second half(right) of linked list.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node{
  int data;
  struct Node* next;
};

void append(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{

  struct Node* new_node=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  new_node->data=new_data;
  new_node->next=NULL;

  struct Node* last=*head_ref;
  if(*head_ref==NULL){
      *head_ref=new_node;
      return;
  }

while(last->next!=NULL)
    last=last->next;

last->next=new_node;
return;

}

int display(struct Node* n)
{
  int m=0;
  printf("\n");
  while(n!=NULL)
  {
      printf(" %d ",n->data);
      n=n->next;
      m=m+1;
  }

return m;
}

void reverse(struct Node** head_ref, int mid)
{
if(*head_ref==NULL)
{
    printf("\nEmpty List cannot be reversed");
    return;
}

struct Node* last=*head_ref;
struct Node* second_last;
struct Node* beg=*head_ref;
int c=1;
while(c<=mid){
    second_last=last;
    last=last->next;
    c=c+1;
}

struct Node* prev=NULL;
struct Node* current=last;
struct Node* next;

while(current != NULL)
{
    next=current->next;
    current->next=prev;
    prev=current;
    current=next;
}
*head_ref=beg;
second_last->next=prev;

}

int main()
{
int size;
struct Node* head=NULL;
int i,mid;
for(i=0;i<11;i++)
{
    append(&head,rand()%19 +1);
}
size=display(head);
printf("\n Size of linked list: %d",size);

if(size%2==0)
    mid=(size+1)/2;
else
    mid=size/2;

reverse(&head, mid);
display(head);
return 0;
}
```